# JSON duplicated properties validation via Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, specifications

I use Jackson and want to check that input JSON string doesn't contain duplicated properties like:

`{"a" : 1, "a" : 0}`

Following Jackson fragment process input string without any errors and even return value:

`JsonNode jsonSelect = mapper.readTree("{ A : 1, A : 0}");
 System.out.println(jsonSelect.getFieldValue("A")); // prints 0`

Does I have a chance to validate duplicates via Jackson?

P.S. Does JSON format support duplicated properties at all? I didn't find any restrictions about it in [specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). Also `org.json.JSONObject` throws an exception for duplicates that doesn't give me an answer - is `{"a" : 1, "a" : 0}` well-formed according to standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON specification indicates duplicates are not consider valid, but parsers are not required to do anything about them. From practical perspective, keeping track of all seen properties adds overhead, which may not make sense at streaming parser level.

As to Jackson, it used to have duplicate detection at data binding level, but I think that is not enabled at this point. It could be added fairly easily when dealing with Maps.
If this is something you would want, filing a feature request or asking on user list might make sense (esp. to see if others would want this feature too, making it more likely to get added soon).

If all you want to do is just validation, you could create a Map subclass, make it throw exception on duplicate. Or, just set a flag in sub-class that you can check if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

JSON does not support duplicated properties.  So if your input is guaranteed to be valid JSON you don't have to check for them.

Comment: No, my input doesn't guarantee that JSON is valid.

Comment: What specification saying that it's incorrect JSON? Didn't find such restriction on json.org

Comment: JSON is based on JavaScript object literal syntax.  A JavaScript object is a collection of named values ('properties').  If you want to associate many values with one name, you would use an array-valued property: { "a": [1, 0] }.  Javascript supporting duplicate property names is kind of like Java supporting duplicate instance variable names.

Comment: `JSON.parse('{"a": true,"a": true}')
Object {a: true}` in latest chrome, so it's invalid JSON but native JSON parsing does not catch this, so yes, you do have to check